# How can I change Route URL to Physical URL? (ASP.NET Web Form)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes

How can I change Route URL that browser shows on address bar to Physical URL on ASP.NET Web Forms from code-behind?

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: @bernlim: Imagine a user came to my web site, "www.mysite.com/dic/word" , I'm using asp.net web forms routing! after that he/she do something(ajax), I just want to change browser address bar without reloading the page